# How to create front wall for these walls?

Tags: modeling

I tried making a loop cut at the spot presented in the picture, then grabbing the bottom faces and extruding downwards and finally making the faces flat in the same height.

That leaves me with not so bad but really kinda weird result, like you know there is a better and proper way. I always had trouble figuring it out, sometimes i do it like i said, sometimes i create separate mesh with the shape intended.

What do you suggest?

[image]

Comment: No reply to the answers posted?

Answer (score 9):

A simple way to create a wall with nice topology.

1. Select your vertices and go *Vertex > New Face*
2. *Inset* the wall a bit (might be useful later) and uncheck *Boundary*
3. Subdivide the bottom edge (*Edge > Subdivide*)
4. Connect the vertices to keep quad topology (*Vertex > Connect Vertex Path*)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for editing it. It is very helpful. I never knew I could do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you will use the same modifiers on all the pieces you can make them inside the same object but as separated meshes (not connected with the other mesh).
If you need to apply different modifiers you'll need to have different objects.